# Why Do I Have To Click the Div Twice the 1st Time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running a jQuery script and its working fine, but I have something of a toggle function that slides a div in and out when you click on it. The 1st time you have to double click it to make it work I'd love to remove this. Anyone know why its happening? Here is what I mean
http://www.gregtaylordesignstudio.com/great-Lakes-Project/actions.html

Here is the script

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
      //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
      $("#click").click(function(){ 
        $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
        return false;
      });
      var slideout = $('#actionsBlurb');
      $('#dots').hide();
      $('#mapBack').delay(1000).animate({top:"45px"},800).fadeOut(400);
      $('#mapBackTop').delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
      slideout.delay(4000).animate({ right: 175, }, { duration: 1000, easing: 'easeOutExpo'});                   
      var open = true;
      $(".close").click(function () {
        if(open === false) {
          open = true;
          slideout.animate({ top: '-170px'}, { queue: false, duration: 500 });$('#dots').fadeIn(2000); 
        }  else if(open === true) {
          open = false;
          slideout.animate({ top: 0}, { queue: false, duration: 500});$('#dots').fadeOut(1000); 
        }

      });
    })

;
```

Comment: Would you *please* clean up the indentation of your code before posting. Just because you don't care what your code looks like doesn't mean others want to look at a mess.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I'd guess that the issue is that you're starting out `var open = true`, when in fact the div starts out closed.

Comment: I would use console.log or alert messages to figure out whether the event is not being received, or whether there's a logic issue.

Comment: your example URL is 404'd too

Comment: Thank you Cookie Monster. You were correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
var open = true;
      $(".close").click(function () {
        if(open == false) {
          open = true;
          slideout.animate({ top: '-170px'}, { queue: false, duration: 500 });$('#dots').fadeIn(2000); 
        }  else{
          open = false;
          slideout.animate({ top: 0}, { queue: false, duration: 500});$('#dots').fadeOut(1000); 
        }

      });
```